# Fields of application of meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, systematic-review

Systematic reviews and meta-analyses have been used extensively in many fields and for many years. For instance, there are exceedingly numerous examples of systematic reviews and meta-analyses in medicine, psychology, physics, economics, and politics.

I am wondering in which other fields of research there have been formal applications of systematic reviews, meta-analyses and related methods.

Answer (score 3):

Other areas include:

- Biology and especially ecology and evolution. There is even an entire book about it ([Koricheva, J., Gurevitch, J., & Mengersen, K. (Eds.) (2013). Handbook of meta-analysis in ecology and evolution. Princeton University Press](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691137293)).
- Crime and justice, education, social welfare, and other public/social policy related topics, all covered by the [Campbell Collaboration](https://www.campbellcollaboration.org/).
- Astronomy (e.g., [Vallee, J. P. (2005). The spiral arms and interarm separation of the Milky Way: An updated statistical study. The Astronomical Journal, 130(2), 569-575](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/431744)).

Comment: One could perhaps ask "In what fields of quantitative research has meta-analysis _not_ been applied?".